# I'm unsure exactly why the 'counter' variable isn't responding in the way I would like it to

Tags: c++

Please bear with me since I am *very* new to C++ and coding in general.To the point where this is my second or third time using arrays. Here is the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int day,month,counter;
    int year[12]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    cout<<"Input a day of a month";
    cin>>day;
    cout<<"Input the month of the year";
    cin>>month;
    for(int x=0;x>12;x++)
    {
        cin>>year[x];
        counter+=year[x];
    }
    
    cout<<"The Date is " <<day<<" / "<<month<<" and, "<<endl;
    cout<<"The number of days until this date is reached again is:"<<counter<<endl;
}
```

I am trying to have the code show an imputed date by the user and the number of days until that date is reached again. However the counter variable is only showing 0. I am decently sure this is some form of logic error I have yet to find.

Comment: `for(int x=0;x>12;x++)` --> `for(int x=0;x<12;x++)` and you need to initialize `counter`.

Comment: Initialize `counter` variable. It's a POD type which will be unitialized unless you explicitly initialize to some other value.

Comment: Don't forget about leap-years.

Comment: `cin>>year[x];` seems like something you don't want. `year` is also not very good variable name for what it contains. Something like `daysPerMonth` is more descriptive.

Comment: @cigien Thank you. this helped alot

Answer (score 0):

Your loop
`for(int x=0;x>12;x++)`
sets x to 0 and then checks if it's greater than 12, which it isn't, and thus ends doing nothing.